# How do we remove Salesforce Header in a Lightning Page?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, aura

I want to remove Salesforce Header Tabs from a lightning page. Can we do that?
[image: Salesforce Header Tabs.]

The component code is as below:

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global"> body here.</aura:component>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't. It will always appear as long as you're in the Lightning Experience. If you're using a Lightning App, it wouldn't ordinarily appear.

Comment: unnhmm, Thanks @sfdcfox. So, there is no work around for this?

Comment: @SFDCMafia-VIC I wish I had a better answer for you, but basically, you can't. It's part of the UI. If you want to have a full-page experience, you should navigate to a Lightning App.

Comment: if you want things to get ugly, chrome plugin to hide it.

Answer (score 1):

You can't remove the Salesforce header from the Lightning Experience but as @sfdcfox mentioned you can create your own Lightning application with a dedicated URL.

1. Using the Developer Console or your favorite IDE create a Lightning Application (let's call it `myApp` for example).
2. Place your components in the myApp.app markup.
3. Access your app via this url:

   https://.lightning.force.com/c/myApp.app

Answer (score 0):

Navigating to Lightning app (Standard app) does give you the full page experience, but the caveat is now you cannot use tags like e:forceeditrecord. 
And using the Standalone app will do no good, as the Salesforce tabs do not go away.